# Mongodb Pymongo create an index for nested object

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have an object like so:

```
{
    "field1": "somestring",
    "field2": {
        "nestedfield1": "somestring",
        "nestedfield2": "somestring"
    }
}
```

i can create an index on field1 like so `db.collection.createIndex('field1')` and it will work as expected. But what if I want an index on both nested fields.

Do I have to do `db.collection.createIndex('field2.nestedfield1')` to create that index or will `db.collection.createIndex('field2')` automatically create that?

I will be searching using 'field2.nestedfield1' in my queries and want an index for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't index nested field at once, you have to index each item inside separately.

To create an index on the nested field, just give its full field path with . separator,

```
db.collection.createIndex('field2.nestedfield1')
```